# Waiting for a sound to stop before playing the next sound

Tags: javascript, audio, phaser-framework

Hi I have built an app in Phaser and want to create a sequence of two sounds:

1. "You have" (loaded and stored as audioSound[0])
2. "Finished" (ditto, audioSound[1])

I can then keep re-using 1 and have different words/sentences in 2. To do this I need the sounds to play in sequence.

At the moment using:

```
audioSound[0].play();

audioSound[1].play();

othercode...
```

Plays both at the same time. Any ideas on how to get the sounds to play in sequence and only continue to `othercode...` once the second one has finished?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: after @Julian's answer**
Hi - to be clear I have the following code to pop items onto a queue and then play them. Although the items on the queue play in sequence, the function/code that comes after the queue play event gets executed in parallel with the sound not when the sound(s) have finished.

```
function playSequence(soundArray) {
    soundArray[0].play();
    soundArray.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        if (soundArray[index + 1]) {
            soundArray[index].onStop.addOnce(function() {
                soundArray[index + 1].play();
                }, this);
            }
        });
```

Comment: use media events https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Comment: I have not finished understanding your question, my friend. Do you want to play two sounds in sequence (you play one and once you finish playing then the second plays) and so infinitely? You also talk about continuing with a different code, does that mean?

Comment: Hey thanks both. @ Julian - I would like for the sounds to play sequentially. What's happens at the moment is that sounds 1 plays at the same time as sound 2 and then the code after both begins to be execute. I would ideally like sounds to play sequentially before executing other code after them. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
function preload() {

    game.load.audio('sound-explosion', 'explosion.wav');
    game.load.audio('sound-lose', 'lose.mp3');

}

var soundlose;
var soundexplosion;

function create() {
    //Add sounds
    soundexplosion = game.add.audio('sound-explosion');
    soundlose = game.add.audio('sound-lose');

    //Prepare the next event once the sound finishes playing
    soundexplosion.onStop.addOnce(function() { soundlose.play(); }, this);
    soundlose.onStop.addOnce(function() { console.log('Hello!'); }, this)

    //Play sound...
    soundexplosion.play();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Julian - once I do this, the audio does play in sequence but the execution of the code continues in parallel with the audio playing - how do I make the execution of the code wait until the audio has finished? (see edited q above)

Comment: Wow! If you want to execute the code after the event, try to place the onStop in the last element of the array: `soundArray[soundArray.length - 1].onStop...`